Stoichiometry of Neutralisation Reaction
For the following question, though the answers are available on web, none of them are providing exact reason behind WHY the specific formula was used.
Question -
What Volume (in $\pu{mL}$) of $\pu{0.2 M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$ solution should be mixed with the $\pu{40 mL}$ of $\pu{0.1 M}\ \ce{NaOH}$ solution such that the resulting solution has the concentration of $\ce{H2SO4}$ as $\pu{\frac{6}{55} M}$.
Approach and Confusions:

This is a neutralisation neaction. So I wrote balanced equation as,
$$\ce{2 NaOH(aq) + H2SO4(aq) -> Na2SO4(aq) + 2 H2O(l)}$$

As per the question, formed solution contains $\pu{\frac{6}{55} M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$.
Hence, I considered that originally, amount in moles of $\ce{H2SO4}$ must be greater. I wrote the equation as,
$$\ce{2x NaOH(aq) + ($x+y$) H2SO4(aq) -> y H2SO4(aq) + x Na2SO4(aq) + 2x H₂O(l)}$$

From the question, $\dfrac{y\ \ce{H2SO4} }{ V [\text{L}]} = \pu{\dfrac{6}{55} M}$


I considered volume of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ to be negligible as it's solid, and without this assumption I was unable to proceed further. [editor note: will be dissolved]

Again from the question, $\pu{40 mL}\ \pu{0.1 M}\ \ce{NaOH} = \pu{0.004 mol} = 2x$.

After this I wasn't able to calculate the exact value of volume $\pu{0.2 M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$ which was $\pu{70 mL}$.
Please assist about the correct answer. It would be helpful if you analysed my approach and told where or why it's not working.

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Consider this: what is the volume of the resulting solution?

@Poutnik But the reaction is between H₂SO₄ and NaOH, not about KOH. Yes, expressing molar concentration as a function as you said will help, but I don't understand how to do that.

I choose another approach, to get the same final solution : $70$ mL of $0.2$ M $\ce{H2SO4}$.
I divide the problem in two parts : First neutralize precisely the amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ and then add enough $\ce{H2SO4}$ to the neutral solution to get a final $\ce{H2SO4}$ concentration equal to $6/55$ M.
First part : Neutralization. The initial solution is $40$ mL $0.1$ M $\ce{NaOH}$. It contains then $4.0$ millimol $\ce{NaOH}$. This needs $2.0$ millimol $\ce{H2SO4}$ to be neutralized. This required amount is included in a volume $\pu{V_o}$ of $0.2$ M $\ce{H2SO4}$. $$\ce{V_o = \frac{n}{c} = \frac{2 mmol}{0.2mmol/L}= 10 mL}$$ After this operation the volume of the solution is $40 + 10 = 50$ mL, and it is a solution of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ .
Second part : Dilution of acid by adding a volume $\ce{V_1}$ of $0.2$ M $\ce{H2SO4}$ (containing $\ce{n_1}$ moles $\ce{H2SO4}$) to $50$ mL of the then neutral solution of $\ce{Na2SO4}$. The final concentration $\ce{c_f}$ = $\ce{\frac{6}{55}}$ is given by : $$\ce{c_f =  \frac{n_1}{V_1 + 0.05} = \frac{V_1* 0.2}{V_1 + 0.05} = \frac{6}{55}}$$ $$\ce{V_1* 0.2 = \frac{6}{55}(V_1 + 0.05)}$$ After multiplication on both sides by $11$ : $$\ce{2.2*V_1 = \frac{6}{5} (V_1 + 0.05) = 1.2 V_1 + 0.06}$$ This corresponds to an addition of $\ce{V_1 = 0.06 L = 60 mL}$ of  $0.2$ M $\ce{H2SO4}$ .
The total volume of used $0.2$ M $\ce{H2SO4}$ is :
$$\ce{V_o + V_1 = 10 mL + 60 mL = 70 mL}$$

It is my second approach, more verbosely presented. :-) It could be easier to follow for a beginner.

Using $\pu{x mL}$ of $\pu{0.2 M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$ brings $0.2x\ \pu{mmol}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$.
There is spend $\frac{\pu{40 mL} \times \pu{0.1 mmol mL-1}}{2}\  = \pu{2 mmol}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$.
There is remaining $0.2x\ \pu{mmol} -\pu{ 2 mmol}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$,
of molar concentration $$\dfrac{0.2x\ \pu{mmol} -\pu{ 2 mmol}}{40\ \pu{mL} + x\ \pu{mL}}=\dfrac{0.2x - 2 }{40 + x} \ \pu{mol L-1} = \pu{\frac{6}{55} mol L-1}$$
this leads to a simple linear algebraic equation:
$$0.2x - 2 = (40 + x)\frac{6}{55}$$
$$x(0.2 - \frac{6}{55}) = \frac{240}{55} + 2$$
$$x(\frac{11-6}{55}) = \frac{240+110}{55}$$
$$5x = 350$$
$$x = 70$$
The required volume of $\pu{0.2 M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$ is then $\ce{70 mL}$.

Another approach: there is spent $\ce{10 mL}$ of $\ce{H2SO4}$ solution on $\pu{40 mL}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$ solution, it makes 50 mL of liquid without any $\ce{H2SO4}$.
Then by the rule the concetration is reciprocal to dilution. It can be seen also as the equivalent task - what volume of $\pu{0.2 M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$ should be taken to get concentration $\pu{\frac{6}{55} M}$ by diluting it by $\ce{50 mL}$ of water:
$$\frac{x-10}{x+40} = \dfrac{(\frac{6}{55})}{(\frac{11}{55})} = 6/11$$
$$(x-10)11 = 6(x+40)$$
$$5x = 240+110=350$$
$$x = 70$$
The required volume of $\pu{0.2 M}\ \ce{H2SO4}$ is then $\pu{70 mL}$.
